# IllegalStateException when HTTP Streaming using ResponseBodyEmitter in Spring-MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception

I'm using the newly added HTTP Streaming feature with ResponseBodyEmitter in Spring 4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.

I would like to implement a long running persistent TCP connection on an undending stream of data between a (possibly java) client and server until the client breaks the connection. I would like to avoid using the websocket protocol.

1. If a client breaks the connection while streaming, a runtime IllegalStateException is thrown. I would like to handle this gracefully and cleanup the emitter. Short of catching a runtime exception, is there any way to gracefully handle this?
2. I have to specify an artifically high timeout value on the emitter for a "persistent" connection. Can I set no timeout?

The webapp is deployed on apache-tomcat-7.0.62.

Relevant code as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "stream", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseBodyEmitter handleStreaming() {
    ResponseBodyEmitter emitter = new ResponseBodyEmitter(timeout);
    emitters.add(emitter);
    emitter.onCompletion(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            emitters.remove(emitter);
        }
    });
    emitter.onTimeout(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            emitters.remove(emitter);
        }
    });
    return emitter;
}
```

.

```
    while (true) {
        for (Iterator<ResponseBodyEmitter> iterator = emitters.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            ResponseBodyEmitter emitter = iterator.next();
            try {
                emitter.send("data...", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
            } catch (IOException | IllegalStateException e) {
                LOGGER.error(e);
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            LOGGER.error(e);
        }
    }
```

Logs:

```
INFO: An error occurred in processing while on a non-container thread. The connection will be closed immediately
java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(InternalOutputBuffer.java:215)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:480)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.flush(InternalOutputBuffer.java:119)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.action(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:801)
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:363)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.flush(CoyoteOutputStream.java:101)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    at org.springframework.util.StreamUtils.copy(StreamUtils.java:106)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(StringHttpMessageConverter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(StringHttpMessageConverter.java:40)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:193)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseBodyEmitterReturnValueHandler$HttpMessageConvertingHandler.sendInternal(ResponseBodyEmitterReturnValueHandler.java:157)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseBodyEmitterReturnValueHandler$HttpMessageConvertingHandler.send(ResponseBodyEmitterReturnValueHandler.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseBodyEmitter.sendInternal(ResponseBodyEmitter.java:180)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseBodyEmitter.send(ResponseBodyEmitter.java:164)
    ....

[ERROR] [02/07/15 18:11 PM] [Controller$TestResponseBodyEmitter:74] - java.lang.IllegalStateException: The request associated with the AsyncContext has already completed processing.
```

Command:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/myapp/stream -v -N
data...data...
Ctrl-C
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I wonder why is the time-out necessary. It seems to kill the purpose of SSE, but maybe I misunderstood the concept...

Answer (score 0):

According to the Javadoc of the ResponseBodyEmitter's constructor (found [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseBodyEmitter.html#ResponseBodyEmitter-java.lang.Long-)).

> Create a ResponseBodyEmitter with a custom timeout value. By default
>   not set in which case the default configured in the MVC Java Config or
>   the MVC namespace is used, or if that's not set, then the timeout
>   depends on the default of the underlying server.

Therefore do *give a timeout when you create the c instance*.

PS: In my environment ResponseBodyEmitter#getTimeout() returned null; this does not mean that there is an infinite timeout. On the contrary after 5-10 sec the connection timed out.